# MethodNotAllowedHttpException when trying to post data to controller via ajax in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, voyager

I'm trying to send dynamically generated data to controller via ajax in laravel. When user select an option from the dropdown then along with selected option and other data should be sent to controller.

I've tried to send data to controller when an option from dropdown is selected. But every time i try this error,

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   and in the error 
>   REQUEST_METHOD is GET

This is the where i call the ajax function

```
$(document).on('change', '.route-code-selector', function() {
      var selectorID = $(this).attr('id');
      addRoutePlanDetails(selectorID);
 });
```

AJAX function

```
function addRoutePlanDetails(selectorID) {
    var routePlanCode = document.getElementById("routeplanno").value;
    var driver = $("#selectDriver").val().split('|');
    var salesman = $("#selectSalesman").val().split('|');
    var router_01 = $("#selectRouter01").val().split('|');
    var router_02 = $("#selectRouter02").val().split('|');
    var vehicle_no = document.getElementById("enterVehicleNo").value;
    var route_code = document.getElementById(selectorID).value;
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value;

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'addNewRoute',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        routePlanCode: routePlanCode,
        driver: driver[1],
        salesman: salesman[1],
        router_01: router_01[1],
        router_02: router_02[1],
        vehicle_no: vehicle_no,
        route_code: route_code,
        date: date
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
}
```

Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();

    Route::get ('route-plan', 'RoutePlanController@index');
    Route::get ('excludePorterRes', 'RoutePlanController@excludePorterRes');
    Route::get ('retreiveRouteData', 'RoutePlanController@retrieveRouteCodeData');
    Route::get ('retreiveUserData', 'RoutePlanController@retreiveUserData');
    Route::get ('retreiveNewRouteData', 'RoutePlanController@retreiveNewRouteData');

    Route::post('addNewRoute', [
        'uses' => 'RoutePlanController@insertNewRoute',
        'as' => 'addNewRoute'
    ]);
});
```

controller

```
public function insertNewRoute(){

    $routeplan = new Routeplan;
    $user_email = auth()->user()->email;

    $routeplan->RouteplanCode = Input::get('routePlanCode');
    $routeplan->RouteCode = Input::get('route_code');
    $routeplan->DriverID = Input::get('driver');
    $routeplan->SalesmanID = Input::get('salesman');
    $routeplan->Routercode1 = Input::get('router_01');
    $routeplan->Routercode2 = Input::get('router_02');
    $routeplan->VehicleNo = Input::get('vehicle_no');
    $routeplan->Date = Input::get('date');
    $routeplan->Createuser = $user_email;
    $routeplan->Status = 'TEMP';

    $routeplan->save();
}
```

when user select an option all the data should be stored in the db.

Comment: `url: 'addNewRoute',` does that route exist? Because you prefixed it in your routes file

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` to make sure your route actually exists. (`php artisan route:clear` to clear the cached routes)

Comment: this will add `/addNewRoute` to the present url on the window rather it should be relative to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try it once

```
url: '{{ route('addNewRoute') }}',
```

Comment: I still get the error 500 Internal Server Error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that and how that solves the exception given in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
url: 'addNewRoute',
```

here you are calling the route in a wrong manner, use it like:

```
url: '{{ url('admin/addNewRoute') }}',
```

you have to call the `url()` method so that it can create the right url format and don't forget the `addNewRoute` is grouped under `admin`, so you have to append that to while calling it.

Comment: I still get the error 500 Internal Server Error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Answer (score 0):

You have used `prefix` for your routes. So all your route in group will be `prefix/uri`.
So in `ajax` call you should `url: '{{ url('admin/addNewRoute') }}',` and change `method` to `type`

```
 $.ajax({
url: '{{ url('admin/addNewRoute') }}',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: {
    routePlanCode: routePlanCode,
    driver: driver[1],
    salesman: salesman[1],
    router_01: router_01[1],
    router_02: router_02[1],
    vehicle_no: vehicle_no,
    route_code: route_code,
    date: date
},
success: function() {
    console.log("success");
}
});
```

In `ajax` for specifying `HTTP Verb` use `type` not `method`.

Comment: I still get the error 500 Internal Server Error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @Kasun its not ```method``` its ```type``` in ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

If ajax method is runs in external javascript file, you should define a url variable in the `blade` (generally it layout blade.) that using as ajax request url on the ajax call method. (before .js file is loaded);

Example  `var url = '{{ route('addNewRoute') }}'`

```
$.ajax({
    url: url',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        routePlanCode: routePlanCode,
        driver: driver[1],
        salesman: salesman[1],
        router_01: router_01[1],
        router_02: router_02[1],
        vehicle_no: vehicle_no,
        route_code: route_code,
        date: date
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

If you using ajax in the blade, you can use directly `route` as ajax request url.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{ route('addNewRoute') }}",
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        routePlanCode: routePlanCode,
        driver: driver[1],
        salesman: salesman[1],
        router_01: router_01[1],
        router_02: router_02[1],
        vehicle_no: vehicle_no,
        route_code: route_code,
        date: date
    },
    success: function() {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `/` in your routes.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
```

Add `/` in `admin/`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/'], function () {
```

Then you can try this in your ajax

```
url: '{{ url('admin/addNewRoute') }}',
```

or

```
url: 'admin/addNewRoute',
```

Try if this will work.

Comment: No need for `/` in route prefix

Answer (score 0):

if your script is in blade file then use `route()` to set url in ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{route('addNewRoute')}}',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Please use **url: '{{ route('addNewRoute') }}'** instead of url: 'addNewRoute'.

Answer (score 0):

As many of you said.. I changed method to type.. And it still didn't work. But then i looked at laravel logs (storage/logs) and from the logs i found that some of my controller syntax are incorrect. And that's why it still gave me the 500 error. After I changed the syntax and do the corrections. It worked !! Anyways thanks for helping guys! If anyone is getting this error even if your ajax is correct take a look at laravel logs.. Hope this helps someone.